# Convert pandas DataFrame to stacked dictionary with concatenated index and column values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I start with a pandas dataframe, that I convert to a dictionary. Then I want to modify the dictionary keys to be like:

```py
df.to_dict()
>{2178: {'choice_0': 96,
  'choice_1': 82,
  'choice_2': 25,
  'choice_3': 38,
  'choice_4': 41,
  'choice_5': 4,
  'choice_6': 24,
  'choice_7': 3,
  'choice_8': 61,
  'choice_9': 9,
  'n_people': 4},
 1374: {'choice_0': 4,
  'choice_1': 1,
  'choice_2': 3,
  'choice_3': 53,
  'choice_4': 26,
  'choice_5': 31,
  'choice_6': 2,
  'choice_7': 10,
  'choice_8': 50,
  'choice_9': 75,
  'n_people': 3}}
```

And I will like it to transform to:

```
2178choice_0 : 96,
2178choice_1 : 82,
.
.
.
1374choice_9 : 75,
1374n_people : 3,
```

Comment: Why would you want this? You should be using lists for repeated items, not sequential keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with pandas directly. First `stack`, then concat the index levels, and *then* convert to dict.

```
df = df.stack()
df.index = df.index.map('{0[1]}{0[0]}'.format)
df.to_dict()
# {'1374choice_0': 4,
#  '1374choice_1': 1,
#  '1374choice_2': 3,
#  '1374choice_3': 53,
#  ...
```

A little explanation of what `{0[1]}{0[0]}` is: It is a format string, the "0" refers to the index (it is passed as a *tuple* to `format` as the first and only argument, so we use "0" to access it). "0[1]" is the second level, and "0[0]" is the first level.

Comment: Feel free to change the title to what you think it adapts more to the question

Answer (score 2):

We can use dictionary comprehension for this:

```
result = {
    f'{k1}{k2}': v
    for k1, d1 in data.items()
    for k2, v in d1.items()
}
```

with `data` the original dictionary (with subdictionaries as values).

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> pprint(result)
{'1374choice_0': 4,
 '1374choice_1': 1,
 '1374choice_2': 3,
 '1374choice_3': 53,
 '1374choice_4': 26,
 '1374choice_5': 31,
 '1374choice_6': 2,
 '1374choice_7': 10,
 '1374choice_8': 50,
 '1374choice_9': 75,
 '1374n_people': 3,
 '2178choice_0': 96,
 '2178choice_1': 82,
 '2178choice_2': 25,
 '2178choice_3': 38,
 '2178choice_4': 41,
 '2178choice_5': 4,
 '2178choice_6': 24,
 '2178choice_7': 3,
 '2178choice_8': 61,
 '2178choice_9': 9,
 '2178n_people': 4}
```

Comment: Feel free to change the title to what you think it adapts more to the question